# Morning Star Integration

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, formulas, stocks

I've been trying to make a comprehensive Google Sheet containing information about different stocks that can have stocks dynamically added and removed for a school project. To that end, I've done some research into loading data from tables with `IMPORTHTML`, and come up with this:

`=IMPORTHTML(CONCAT("http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=", B3),"table", 1)`

Where B3 is NFLX or any other stock ticker that would be added. However, Sheets is returning with `Imported content is empty", and I've got no clue why.

Comment: The reason your importhtml is not working is because morningstar fills that information using AJAX ...

Comment: @AhmedMasud Ahh... Any way that I could interface with AJAX?

Comment: @AhmedMasud Do you have a way to get that file for the Ownership category as well?

Answer (score 0):

## Partial Answer:

yes, after a bit of fiddling I found that the best url to look at for Financial Parts is

> http://financials.morningstar.com/finan/financials/getFinancePart.html?t=XNAS:NFLX&region=usa&culture=en-US&ops=clear

You can use this and combine it with

> https://github.com/fastfedora/google-docs/blob/master/scripts/ImportJSON/Code.gs

which adds ImportJSON functionality to google sheets.

This should get you started. However the data comes as bunch of divs/tds that you would have to clean it up but it's possible after a bit of fiddling :)

Comment: May I ask where you got that other URL? I've been looking for a similar one for Key Ratios

Comment: Also one for Ownership

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you where Ahmed Masud got the link (and I would like to know too). I get a lot
of data from morningstar and they can be strange. However, using his link, you can get the 
Key Ratios and clean the resulting data with importhtml and also reference your B3 cell with this:

```
   =arrayformula(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTHTML("http://financials.morningstar.com/finan/financials/getFinancePart.html?t=XNAS:"& B3 &"&region=usa&culture=en-US&ops=clear","table", 1), "<\/td>" , "" ),"<\/tr>",""),"<\/th>",""),"<\/thead>",""),"<\/span>",""))
```

Sorry, I put in the wrong formula. This will get the B3 entry.

This will get ownership:

```
=arrayformula(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTHTML("http://investors.morningstar.com/ownership/shareholders-overview.html?t=XNAS:"& B3 &"&region=usa&culture=en-US&ops=clear","table", 4), "<\/td>" , "" ),"<\/tr>",""),"<\/th>",""),"<\/thead>",""),"<\/span>",""))
```

Again the stock symbol should be in B3.

Comment: Yeah, that works really well. How do you get your data? Or is it only the Key Ratios stuff?